# issue with compiling delegate methods as static library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, static-libraries

i'v recently gone through concept of static library where i can put & compile my methods and later on i can import them to various projects. now i'm having some delegate methods carrying some functionality which are,

```
-(BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;

-(void)ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;

-(void)ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

same methods i wanted to repeat in my multiple projects so is there any way to reuse those methods by compiling it as library?

Comment: im not quite getting what you want. If they are delegate methods declare them in a public header for your projects which use the library to implement if required. can you explain further?

Comment: let me explain what i did last... i had some normal methods which were doing some calculations and i had required those methods in my multiple projects.. so i successfully created lib of those methods and i can import those lib in my projects and call those methods by making object of respective class. -----------

now i feel above mentioned case something different,these methods are delegating methods which give callbacks on various touch events so im not able to follow same procedure which i did in first paragraph. may be another approach then lib will be helpful here

Comment: well i got one solution... i have to declared these methods in my class and in these methods i had called my library methods which solved my point !\